# Creating arrays in JavaScript by comparing values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In JavaScript, I'm trying to create arrays based on the values of another array and I'm having difficultly.

I've got an array of dates in string format (dates) e.g.

```
["30/09/2015", "31/10/2015", "30/11/2015", "31/12/2015"]
```

I've got an Object to represent multiple bank accounts (balancesSortByAccId) e.g.

```
Cash - (Array size: 3)
id: 1, date: "30/09/2015", balance: 30
id: 2, date: "31/10/2015", balance: 50
id: 3, date: "30/11/2015", balance: 100

Natwest - (Array size: 2)
id: 4, date: "30/11/2015", balance: 400
id: 5, date: "31/12/2015", balance: 200
```

Whilst looping through all the accounts in balancesSortByAccId, I want to be able to create an array for the balance at each date in the dates array i.e.

```
[30, 50, 100, null]
[null, null, 400, 200]
```

How could I achieve this?

UPDATE: jsfiddle code - https://jsfiddle.net/gx8bLehb/

Comment: can you give us a fiddle with appropriate array values?

Comment: Please format the strings in your code as actual strings (e.g. with quotes around them).

Comment: @jfriend00 Have done.

Comment: Hey, did any of the answers solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: @JohannesJander I am still attempting to resolve this. I understand that my original question/jsfiddle code isn't clear and so I was wondering whether I should delete this question and re-post again or just modify the OP?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I tried to explain my issue more clearly here with better example code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106083/creating-arrays-in-javascript-for-chart-js

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to transform your `cash` and `natwest` arrays into a hash sorted by date, something like `balancesByDate`:

```
    var balancesByDate = _.groupBy(cash, function(entry) {return entry.date});
```

Then use an array `map()` function, e.g. from lodash to iterate the `dates` array and for each date look up the account line in the `balancesByDate` hash. From that line, return the `balance` property in the `map` function.

```
dates.forEach(function(date){
  if (balancesByDate[date]) {
    results.push(_.map(balancesByDate[date], function(line){
       return line.balance;
    }));
  } else {
    results.push(null);
  }
});
```

However, you need to be aware that your dataset most likely could contain duplicate balances for a day, you should plan for that (my code returns an array for each day).

https://jsfiddle.net/hdpuuc5d/1/

Comment: Or, you know, the built-in [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of importing an extra library... ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: yes, depending on the browser version OP needs to support.

Comment: @JohannesJander How can I transform `balancesSortByAccId` into a hash as you mentioned? I've added a link to jsfiddle with sample data/my code in the OP.

Comment: I have amended my answer in response to the fiddle. Unfortunately, in the fiddle, the data structure is somewhat different than in the question, that's not really nice. Also there were bugs and undeclared variables in the fiddle - please if you want help from people, do check and correct your stuff. Anyhow, here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hdpuuc5d/1/ - please be aware that you can have more than one balance result for a given date - therefore the `results`-array contains an array for each day.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain javascript with a helper object for the dates:

```js
var dates = ["30/09/2015", "31/10/2015", "30/11/2015", "31/12/2015"],
    datesObj = dates.reduce(function (r, a, i) { r[a] = i; return r; }, {}),
    balances = {
        Cash: [
            { id: 1, date: "30/09/2015", balance: 30 },
            { id: 2, date: "31/10/2015", balance: 50 },
            { id: 3, date: "30/11/2015", balance: 100 }
        ],
        Natwest: [
            { id: 4, date: "30/11/2015", balance: 400 },
            { id: 5, date: "31/12/2015", balance: 200 }
        ]
    },
    result = {};

Object.keys(balances).forEach(function (k) {
    result[k] = Array.apply(null, { length: dates.length }).map(function () { return null; });
    balances[k].forEach(function (a) {
        result[k][datesObj[a.date]] = a.balance;
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```